# macro to copy and transpose every seventh row and past in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have surveys being done for my agents the system gives me a report in XML format. When I get the same changed to Excel I get the surveys in the below mentioned format

```
Survey number
Agent Name
Rating 1
Rating 2
Rating 3 
Rating 4 
Rating 5
Comments
```

With this format I have around 700 surveys every day and I need to get the same transposed to the below mentioned format

```
Survey number/Agent Name/Rating 1/Rating 2/Rating 3/Rating 4/Rating 5/Comments
```

The problem is the macro goes on and on and the file becomes heavy.

Can anyone help as to how a macro could detect the next survey and automatically copy the data from one sheet and then transpose the same on the next sheet so as to fall right below the earlier line. I do not have much of knowledge in VB.

Comment: Shanky, welcome to stackoverflow! You could edit your question and format the format snippets by prefixing them with 4 spaces (or selecting the line and pressing the Code Sample button). Use the preview to see if it becomes more readable.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the difference between your original and the transposed format?

Answer (score 0):

The following source should do what you want.

It uses the first sheet as source and the second sheet as target.

First search for the first empty cell in the first column of sheet 2.

Then loop over all lines in sheet 1 and copy the data, until we find an empty Survey Number.
Original data is not deleted, uncomment one line to make that happen (see source).

```
Sub transpose()
    Dim sourceRow, targetRow, targetColumn As Integer

    ' find first empty row in target sheet
    targetRow = 1
    While (Sheets(2).Cells(targetRow, 1) <> "")
        targetRow = targetRow + 1
    Wend

    sourceRow = 1
    While (Sheets(1).Cells(sourceRow, 1) <> "")
        For targetColumn = 1 To 8
            ' copy
            Sheets(2).Cells(targetRow, targetColumn) = Sheets(1).Cells(sourceRow, 1)
            ' delete original row (uncomment if required)
            ' Sheets(1).Cells(sourceRow, 1) = ""
            sourceRow = sourceRow + 1
        Next targetColumn
        targetRow = targetRow + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way with just a single loop

```
Public Sub TransposeData()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LastRow Step 8

            .Cells(i, "A").Resize(8).Copy
            NextRow = NextRow + 1
            .Cells(NextRow, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, transpose:=True
        Next i

        .Rows(NextRow + 1).Resize(LastRow - NextRow).Delete
        .Columns(1).Delete
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```