# Macro to copy and transpose every row and past in Cell Q1 Column

Tags: vba, excel

I have village names in column A.as below mentioned format

```
VILLAGE
Campbelbay
Carnicobar
Champin
Chowra
Gandhinagar
Kakana
Kapanga
```

With this format I have around 700 sheets in workbook. I need to get the same transposed to the below mentioned format in Column(cell) Q1.

```
Campbelbay,Carnicobar,Champin,Chowra,Gandhinagar,Kakana,Kapanga
```

I have a macro code works for 8 cells and for one sheet, can somebody help me to apply this macro to all sheets with auto select row number.? i.e, Sheets1 has 30 rows, sheet2 has 50 rows and sheet n has n rows.

I do not have much of knowledge in VB.

Following is the code that works for Sheet1:
Ref:

[macro to copy and transpose every seventh row and past in new sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965600/macro-to-copy-and-transpose-every-seventh-row-and-past-in-new-sheet)

```
Public Sub TransposeData()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow Step 8
            .Cells(i, "A").Resize(8).Copy
            NextRow = NextRow + 1
            .Cells(NextRow, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, transpose:=True
        Next i

        .Rows(NextRow + 1).Resize(LastRow - NextRow).Delete
        .Columns(1).Delete
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You should explain where you want the results, and whether they should be in a single cell or multiple cells - your question is contradictory.

Comment: Agree with @SJR couldn't work out what you wanted presentation wise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim w As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim r As Excel.Range

    For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set r = w.Range("a2", w.Range("a1").End(xlDown))
        w.Range("q1").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(r), ",")
    Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Imran, Thanks a lot...you saved my day.Perfect solution.

Comment: @Ram This the same solution as mine that you said didn't work.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks for your help but your code gave me error, at line "w.Range("q1").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(r.Value), ",")"   the same line is different in IMran's code which is, "w.Range("q1").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(r), ",")"   But run successfully. I am a layman.

Comment: @Imran Malek, Imran can you edit the code to auto fill the q1(in Column Q) result till the end of corresponding cell in Column A.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop the sheets collection `worksheets` and use the `.end` something like so

```
Sub test()

Dim w As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Excel.Range

For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set r = Range("a2", w.Range("a1").End(xlDown))
    w.Range("q1").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(r.Value), ",")

Next w

End Sub
```

Couldn't work out whether you wanted them in the same sheet in Q, if so you'll need to change

`w.Range("q1").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(r.Value), ",")`

to something like

`worksheets("result").range("q1").end(xldown).offset(1,0)=`

Hope this helps, not fully tested the last line.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Nathan, after running macro showing error"range object _global failed excel macro" () and running only in sheet 1. After changing the line showing compile error.

Comment: Sorry, I cant see your screen.

Comment: Can u plz run your code in your system,sheet2 data is    VILLAGE
Little Nicobar
Mildera
Mus
Nancowrie
Nehrugram
Pilomilo Island
Sawai
Shabnamnagar
Teressa
    Trinket
     Aerial Bay
     Bakultala
     Betapur

Comment: No I cant, I have my own job to do, I tested it using data similar to yours and got the results expected.